# Removing "NA" values in R (for some reason na.omit and complete.cases only work on one variable...)

Tags: r

The first part of this assignment is to import data from an external http site; the data contains eight variables with 1,339 observations.  Four of those variables (age, height, weight, igf1) contain NA values within them (NOTE: the other variables may also have NA values, but I'm not concerned with them).  I need to eliminate the NA values in those four variables: this is where I'm struggling.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#imports dataset from internet
importData <- read.table("http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/iswr/juul2.csv", sep=',', header=T)
#inspects the data:
str(importData)
```

Basically, I want to remove ALL NA values in age, height, weight, and igf1.  I'll know I'm successful when I have 858 observations remaining.

Three of the variables (height, weight, igf1) contain FACTOR type information.  One of the variables (age) contains numeric information.  I have been unable to successfully implement complete.cases and/or na.omit across them: those functions only seem to work on $age, where they eliminate the five NA values (but don't touch the other variables)

I need help cutting out the NA values in the remaining variables.  Again, when I'm done, I should have 858 observations.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). As to your question, when you say "remove", do you mean: (a) removing the rows containing `NA` in all four of them? (b) removing the rows containing `NA` in any of them? or (c) changing the `NA` to another value (imputing)?

Comment: I have occasionally somehow managed to convert NA's into a character string "NA" without realising, causing all sorts of downstream problems. Check that you haven't managed the same.

Comment: Thank you, Hugh.  To your question, I mean (A) removing rows containing NA across all four variables.  I want to remove the rows entirely, as opposed to replacing the values.

Comment: Can we see `str(data)`? (`complete.cases` *shouldn't* leave `NA`s in any of the columns, which isn't quite what you want, but it seems you have other problems.)

Comment: Thanks Hugh and Richard.  Please see edits above.

Comment: You have the answer in your call to `str`. All values are between quotes, and R interprets them as factors, not as numbers. `NA` is just a factor level, not a real `NA`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your data file encloses all values in quotes, like this:

```
"age", "height", "menarche", "sex", "igf1", "tanner", "testvol", "weight"
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "90.0", "NA", "NA", "NA"
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "88.0", "NA", "NA", "NA"
```

When R reads that, it takes all values as strings, which by default represent as factors. The `NA`s are just taken as the label for one level of those factors. You can see this with `str`:

```
> str(importData)
'data.frame':   1339 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ age     : num  NA NA NA NA NA 0.17 0.17 0.17 0.17 0.17 ...
 $ height  : Factor w/ 600 levels " 110.8"," 111.5",..: 600 600 600 600 600 600 600 600 600 600 ...
 $ menarche: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1"," 2"," NA": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ sex     : Factor w/ 3 levels " 1.00"," 2.00",..: 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ igf1    : Factor w/ 501 levels " 100.0"," 101.0",..: 490 487 53 55 23 2 498 6 10 474 ...
 $ tanner  : Factor w/ 6 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ testvol : Factor w/ 26 levels " 1"," 10"," 11",..: 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ...
 $ weight  : Factor w/ 518 levels " 14.1"," 17.9",..: 518 518 518 518 518 518 518 518 518 518 ...
```

So read your data without making factors, which reads all as numeric:

```
> importData <- read.csv("http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/iswr/juul2.csv",
                         stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings=c(NA,"NA"," NA"))
> str(importData)
'data.frame':   1339 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ age     : num  NA NA NA NA NA 0.17 0.17 0.17 0.17 0.17 ...
 $ height  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ menarche: int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ sex     : num  NA NA NA NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ igf1    : num  90 88 164 166 131 101 97 106 111 79 ...
 $ tanner  : int  NA NA NA NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ testvol : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ weight  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

and now remove `NA`s:

```
> data <- importData[complete.cases(importData[c("age","height","weight","igf1")]),]
> str(data)
'data.frame':   858 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ age     : num  6 6.08 6.26 6.4 6.42 6.43 6.61 6.63 6.7 6.72 ...
 $ height  : num  112 117 120 116 116 ...
 $ menarche: int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ sex     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ igf1    : num  98 242 196 179 126 142 236 148 174 136 ...
 $ tanner  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ testvol : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ weight  : num  19.1 21.7 24.7 19.6 20.6 20.2 28 21.6 26.1 22.6 ...
```

Comment: This got it.  It was actually very close to a number of things I've tried, but never quite got there on my own.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Why not make things a lot less stressful and read the `.txt` version of the data instead? I found it in the data list on the same page as the `.csv`.  It isn't spaced abnormally like the `.csv` file and there is no fiddling around with `read.csv` arguments (which I did for quite a while before finding the other file).

```
con <- "http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/iswr/juul2.txt"
dat <- read.table(con, header = TRUE)
sapply(dat, class)
#       age    height  menarche       sex      igf1    tanner   testvol    weight 
# "numeric" "numeric" "integer" "numeric" "numeric" "integer" "integer" "numeric" 
cols <- c("age", "height", "weight", "igf1")
resultSet <- dat[complete.cases(dat[cols]), ]
dim(resultSet)
# [1] 858   8
```

Comment: Too localized, but +1 for the best solution to this problem!

Answer (score 4):

Read in your data using `as.is=TRUE` and `na.strings = c(NA, "NA", " NA"))`. Your file has spaces between fields which are interpreted as part of the field.

```
data <- read.table("http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/iswr/juul2.csv", 
        sep=",", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, na.strings=c(NA, "NA", " NA"))
```

If you want to remove rows where *any* of the selected columns are `NA` use `complete.cases`:

```
new.data <- data[complete.cases(data[ ,c("age", "height", "weight", "igf1")]), ]
nrow(new.data)
# [1] 858
```

If you want to remove only the rows where *all* of the selected columns are `NA`, use `rowSums`:

```
new.data <- data[rowSums(is.na(data[ ,c("age", "height", "weight", "igf1")])) < 4, ]
nrow(new.data)
# [1] 1339   # there aren't any such rows :)
```

This isolated the four columns, tests whether they are `NA`, and for each row calculates how many are `NA`, returning only the ones that have fewer than 4 `NA`s in each row.

Comment: Thanks, Hugh.  Implementing this, I'm still left with 1,339 observations - which is telling me it didn't remove the NA values?  Please see example:
> test1 <- importData[rowSums(is.na(importData[ , c("age", "height", "weight", "igf1")])) < 4, ]
> str(test1)
'data.frame': 1339 obs. of  8 variables

Comment: Are you sure there are any rows to delete? I can't see any rows that fit the description. (There are only 5 rows which have `age` NA and they only have three `NA`s in the columns.)

Comment: Thanks, Hugh.  I just edited the everything above to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: You actually wanted option (b), not option (a).

Comment: Thank you, Hugh.  I was more than a little unclear in the original post, sorry about that.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading data from file, use the read.table option bellow:

```
read.table(...,quote="")
```

If you conditionally created NAs, like:

```
df[condition] <- NA
```

make sure you never use it quoted ("NA").